# Is there a max number of Storage-triggered Cloud Functions in firebase?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

Until now I only had one CF that was triggered by Firebase Storage uploads:

```js
export const onAvatarUpload_v1 = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {

// [... something that works, the actual code is at the end of the question]

}
```

This function triggers every time a client uploads an object to Storage. If such an object is uploaded to a specific folder, then the link to that resource (an avatar) is saved to a document in a firestore collection.

This worked fine and dandy until I defined a new CF that is also triggered by Storage uploads:

```js
export const onUserPofilePictureUpdate_v1 = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object, context) => {
    // something that presumably works, but that I have not been able to try, the actual code is at the end of the question
}
```

Now, with both CF deployed, the logs that these CF generate on execution look like this:

```
12:52:31.753 p. m.
assetsManagement-onAvatarUpload_v1
Function execution started

12:52:31.764 p. m.
assetsManagement-onAvatarUpload_v1
undefined

12:52:31.768 p. m.
assetsManagement-onAvatarUpload_v1
Function execution took 17 ms, finished with status: 'error'
```

I haven't tested the second CF. But I am sure that before deploying the second one, the first CF worked. That's what makes me think that there might be some limitation.

Is it correct, is there a limit to how many CFs can be triggered through Storage uploads? Might there be a bug in firebase? There is no `console.log` statement that can be only `undefined`, as I always add the name of the CF to the `console.log` statements. This suggests me that my code doesn't even get to run.

EDIT: I'm adding the code of the two cloud functions.

```js
//This is the one that worked until I deployed the other one.
export const onAvatarUpload_v1 = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
    try {
        const filePath = object.name

        if (!filePath) {
            return Promise.reject(`onAvatarUpload_v1: no filePath`)
        }

        const baseFileName = path.basename(filePath, path.extname(filePath))
        const fileDir = path.dirname(filePath)

        if (fileDir !== 'assets/avatars') {
            return Promise.reject('onAvatarUpload_v1: The file was uploaded to another folder')
        } else {
            console.log(`onAvatarUpload_v1: A file has been uploaded to the /assets/avatars folder`)
        }

        if (!object.contentType?.startsWith('image/')) {
            console.log('onAvatarUpload_v1: Object is not an image. Deleting uploaded resource...')

            const [response] = await admin.storage().bucket().delete(object)

            const http2XXRegExp = /(2)\d{2}/

            if (http2XXRegExp.test(response.statusCode.toString())) {
                console.log(
                    `onAvatarUpload_v1: ${response.statusCode} Successfully deleted object. ${response.statusMessage}`
                )
            } else {
                console.log(
                    `onAvatarUpload_v1: ${response.statusCode} Failed to delete object. ${response.statusMessage}`
                )
            }
        }

        if (!object.mediaLink) {
            return Promise.reject(`onAvatarUpload_v1: object lacks mediaLink`)
        }

        const repository: IDataRepository = new FirestoreRepository()

        const avatarWasCorrectlySaved: boolean = await repository.addAvatar(object.mediaLink)

        if (avatarWasCorrectlySaved) {
            return Promise.resolve(
                `onAvatarUpload_v1: Avatar ${baseFileName} added to assets collection in Firestore`
            )
        } else {
            return Promise.reject(
                `onAvatarUpload_v1: Failed to add ${baseFileName} avatar to assets collection in Firestore`
            )
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return Promise.reject(err)
    }
})
```

```js
//This is the one that I have not been able to try
export const onUserPofilePictureUpdate_v1 = functions.storage
    .object()
    .onFinalize(async (object, context) => {
        try {
            const userId = context.auth?.uid

            if (!userId) {
                return Promise.reject('onUserPofilePictureUpdate_v1: No auth provided')
            }

            const filePath = object.name

            if (!filePath) {
                return Promise.reject(`onUserPofilePictureUpdate_v1: no filePath`)
            }

            const baseFileName = path.basename(filePath, path.extname(filePath))
            const fileDir = path.dirname(filePath)

            if (fileDir !== 'assets/profile') {
                return Promise.reject(
                    'onUserPofilePictureUpdate_v1: The file was uploaded to another folder'
                )
            } else {
                console.log(`onUserPofilePictureUpdate_v1: new file uploaded to ${fileDir}`)
            }

            if (!object.contentType?.startsWith('image/') || baseFileName !== userId) {
                console.log(
                    'onUserPofilePictureUpdate_v1: This is not an image or is incorrectly named. Deleting object...'
                )

                const [response] = await admin.storage().bucket().delete(object)

                const http2XXRegExp = /(2)\d{2}/

                if (http2XXRegExp.test(response.statusCode.toString())) {
                    console.log(
                        `onAvatarUpload_v1: ${response.statusCode} Successfully deleted object. ${response.statusMessage}`
                    )
                } else {
                    console.log(
                        `onAvatarUpload_v1: ${response.statusCode} Failed to delete object. ${response.statusMessage}`
                    )
                }
            }

            if (!object.mediaLink) {
                return Promise.reject(`onUserPofilePictureUpdate_v1: object lacks mediaLink`)
            }

            const repository: IDataRepository = new FirestoreRepository()

            const userProfilePicWasUpdated = await repository.updateUserProfilePicture(
                userId,
                object.mediaLink
            )

            if (userProfilePicWasUpdated) {
                return Promise.resolve(
                    `onUserPofilePictureUpdate_v1: User's profile picture successfuly updated`
                )
            } else {
                return Promise.reject(
                    `onUserPofilePictureUpdate_v1: Could not update the user's profile picture`
                )
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(`onUserPofilePictureUpdate_v1: : ${err}`)
            return Promise.reject(err)
        }
    })
```

Since I deployed both functions, the only output I see in both functions' logs is:

```
8:45:29.305 a. m.
userManagement-onUserPofilePictureUpdate_v1
Function execution started

8:45:29.806 a. m.
userManagement-onUserPofilePictureUpdate_v1
undefined

8:45:29.810 a. m.
userManagement-onUserPofilePictureUpdate_v1
Function execution took 508 ms, finished with status: 'error'
```

And

```
8:49:34.067 a. m.
assetsManagement-onAvatarUpload_v1
Function execution started

8:49:34.085 a. m.
assetsManagement-onAvatarUpload_v1
undefined

8:49:34.086 a. m.
assetsManagement-onAvatarUpload_v1
Function execution took 21 ms, finished with status: 'error'
```

Comment: Can you share your entire code (i.e. the `index.js` or ts file)

Comment: In my `index.ts` file there are only imports of the functions in other files. Which code is the one you need to see? :) @RenaudTarnec

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem to have two CFs triggered in parallel when a file is uploaded to Cloud Storage. The idea is to generally check the way your CFs are managing asynchronous method calls, which is usually the major source of problem.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I have edited the question to include the code of both CFs. This morning the CF `onAvatarUpload_v1` worked once, then again failed. So there is some randomness in the error.

Could the question be reopened? I added the requested information to the best of my ability :)